# transpose column into rows but without using pivot in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have a employee table with employee ID and salary column but i want transpose of that column but without using `pivot` keyword.

original table

### ID  Salary

```
1   10000               
2   20000               
3   30000               
4   40000               
5   50000
```

after select query output like =>>

```
ID      1       2       3       4       5
------  -----   -----   -----   -----   -----
Salary  10000   20000   30000   40000   50000
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NTZz.png)

Comment: See here: https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: Why without using `PIVOT`? That's exactly what it was designed for. Its like saying I want to store some characters on a computer but I'm not allowed to use a string data type; if you have a tool that's right for the job then you should be using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select 'Salary' as id,
       max(case when id = 1 then salary end) as salary_1,
       max(case when id = 2 then salary end) as salary_2,
       max(case when id = 3 then salary end) as salary_3,
       max(case when id = 4 then salary end) as salary_4,
       max(case when id = 5 then salary end) as salary_5
from t;
```